# Ajax callback with db_select in tableselect (Drupal 7)

Tags: ajax, forms

I have some problem with ajax callback. After add a description by Upload button to database I try to dinamically show this result in tableselect, but db_select isn't refresh after callback.

Anybody can solution me?

```
function mymodule_add_desc($form, $form_state) {
  $form['fieldset'] = array(
    '#prefix' => '<div id="callback">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
  );

  $form['fieldset']['description'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Description:'),
    '#maxlength' => 100,
  );

  $form['fieldset']['new'] = array(
    '#type' => 'button',
    '#value' => t('Upload'),
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'mymodule_add_desc',
      'wrapper' => 'callback',
    ),
  );

  $header = array(
    array('data' => t('Description'), 'class' => array('center')),
  );

  $query = db_select('reg_desc', 'd')
  ->extend('TableSort');

  $query->fields('d');

  $result = $query
  ->orderByHeader($header)
  ->execute();

  $rows = array();

  foreach ($result as $desc) {
    $rows[$desc->id] = array(
      array('data' => $desc->info),
    );
  }

  $form['fieldset']['table'] = array(
    '#type' => 'tableselect',
    '#header' => $header,
    '#options' => $rows,
    '#multiple' => true,
  );

  return $form;
}


/*
*
*/

function mymodule_add_desc($form, $form_state) {

  global $user;

  $entry = array(
    'uid' => $user->uid,
    'data' => time(),
    'info' => $form_state['values']['info'],
  );

  $result = entry_insert('reg_desc', $entry);

  return $form['fieldset'];
}
```

Comment: Try this: return on your ajax function `return $form['fieldset']['table']`